# how to print the content in the script based on the value passed to the script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, yaml

i have data in YAML file as below:

```
report_id:youtube
columns:
  - date
  - channel_id
  - video_id
  - claimed_status
  - uploader_type
  - live_or_on_demand
  - subscribed_status
report_id:device
columns:
  - date                              
  - views                             
  - comments                          
  - shares                            
  - channel_id                        
  - watch_time_minutes
```

and many such report_ids and it's column information present.

i have written a script to write the columns into another output file based on the report_id passed in shell script. Below is an example:

```
copy_fields()
{
report_id=`cat $FILE | grep 'report_id: device' | awk '{print $NF}'`

echo "copy $report_id" > $OUTPUT
echo "(" >> $OUTPUT

for i in `cat $FILE | grep - | awk '{print $NF}'`
do
    echo $i
        echo $i >> $OUTPUT
done
echo ")" >> $OUTPUT
}

copy_fields
```

The above columns should write only device information to file "output" but it's writing all the data into "output" file something like below:

```
- date
- channel_id
- video_id
- claimed_status
- uploader_type
- live_or_on_demand
- subscribed_status
- date                              
- views                             
- comments                          
- shares                            
- channel_id                        
- watch_time_minutes
```

The script should write the data into "output" file on basis on report_id passed,if device is passed it should write into "output" as below:

```
  - date                              
  - views                             
  - comments                          
  - shares                            
  - channel_id                        
  - watch_time_minutes.
```

Please help me on this to get the exact code. I need to write a shell script that reads the data from yaml file with passed report_id and able to write that data into another output file with the columns of the report_id.

Comment: Show example of how output should look.

Comment: if report_id is device then output should look like below:
- date
- views
- comments
- shares
- channel_id
- watch_time_minutes
if report_id is youtube output data should consider:
date
- channel_id
- video_id
- claimed_status
- uploader_type
- live_or_on_demand
- subscribed_status

Comment: `awk '/report_id:device/{x=1}x&&/^ *-/' file` ?

Comment: it's not working, it should be irrespective of the report_id passed, only that data should be printed under the passed report_id not complete data

Answer (score 0):

You can try following awk script

```
key='device'
awk -v key=$key '{if(/report_id/){val=$0}else{if(val ~ key){FS=""; print $0}}}' input
```

output is

```
columns:
  - date                              
  - views                             
  - comments                          
  - shares                            
  - channel_id                        
  - watch_time_minutes
```

Comment: OP asked for "irrespective of the report_id passed"

Comment: its giving all the columns in it: used the below code:  
`copy_fields()
{
key='youtube'
report_id= awk -v key=$key '{if(/report_id/){val=$0}else{if(val ~ key){FS=""; print $0}}}'
echo "copy $report_id" > $OUTPUT
echo "(" >> $OUTPUT

for i in `cat $FILE | grep - | awk '{print $NF}'`
do
 echo $i
        echo $i >> $OUTPUT
done
echo ")" >> $OUTPUT
}`

copy_fields

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk!

```
awk -v pat=$a 'c&&!--c{next};($0==pat){p=1;c=1;next} p&&/^report_id:/{p=0};p' file
```

or

```
awk -v pat="report_id:whatever" 'c&&!--c{next};($0==pat){p=1;c=1;next} p&&/^report_id:/{p=0};p' file
```

Output:

```
  - date
  - views
  - comments
  - shares
  - channel_id
  - watch_time_minutes
```

$a = "report_id:device" or "report_id:youtube" or whatever.. could be declared in the bash script

Comment: OP asked for "irrespective of the report_id passed" in comments

Answer (score 0):

Run **./script.sh device file output**

Argumnet 1 report_id

Argument 2 file

Argument 3 OUTPUT file

**script.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
report=$1
file=$2
awk -vrep="$report" 'BEGIN{rep="report_id:"rep} flag && /^report_id/{flag=0} $0 == rep{getline;getline;flag++} flag' $file > $3
```

Use > $3 to override >> $3 to append outputs

**Output**

```
  - date
  - views
  - comments
  - shares
  - channel_id
  - watch_time_minutes
```

**AWK explained**

```
BEGIN{rep="report_id:"rep} #concat variable to report_id
flag && /^report_id/{flag=0} #reset print flag
$0 == rep{getline;getline;flag++} #check for match, if matched the skip to 2nd line and set print flag
flag #print the line
```

---

**EDIT**

RUN : **./script.sh device**

**cat script.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
report=$1
FILE=report_type_id_list.yml
OUTPUT=report_type_id_copy_fields.sh
copy_fields()
{
awk -vrep="$report" 'BEGIN{rep="report_id:"rep ;} flag && /^report_id/{flag=0} $0 == rep{getline;getline;flag++} flag' $FILE > $OUTPUT

}
copy_fields
```

output

**cat report_type_id_copy_fields.sh**

```
  - date
  - views
  - comments
  - shares
  - channel_id
  - watch_time_minutes
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, the script ran but their is no output displayed in the output file.

Comment: Have you ran the same input you have shared

Comment: FILE=report_type_id_list.yml # the file that has the data 
OUTPUT=report_type_id_copy_fields.sh# to write into output file based on the choice of report_id passed.<brk>
copy_fields()
{
report_id=`cat $FILE | grep 'report_id: youtube' | awk '{print $NF}'`
 
echo "copy $report_id" > $OUTPUT
echo "(" >> $OUTPUT

for i in `cat $FILE | grep - | awk '{print $NF}'`
do
 echo $i
        echo $i >> $OUTPUT
done
echo ")" >> $OUTPUT
}

copy_fields
 #can you please edit the above script

Comment: hey @chet thanks for the work. used the code below and the data displaying is again all the columns
report=youtube
FILE=report_type_id_list.yml
OUTPUT=report_type_id_copy_fields.sh
copy_fields()
{
awk -vrep="$report" 'BEGIN{rep="report_type_id:"rep ; print rep} flag && /^report_type_id/{flag=0} $0 == rep{getline;getline;flag++} flag' $FILE >> $OUTPUT

}
copy_fields

Comment: do you want to append data of every run to the OUTPUT file ? or just the last RUN?

Comment: i want data into output file as updated one. Likewise the data is already present in output file, then it should be updated with new data when it runs. We have got number of report_ids in the yaml file so in shell script when a particular report_id is passed it should be able to select the right report_id from the yaml file and replace the data in output file with that passed report_id columns.

Comment: Try now..every time the report id is passed the output is updated

Comment: getting empty in the output file.